# how to convert strings to array in php without using explode function

Tags: php

I want to convert strings to array without using explode function in php
   I want output something like this `( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )` but without using explode().

```
    <?php

     $str="this is string"; 

    ?>
```

should be like this `arr[0]=this arr[1]=is arr[2]=string`

Comment: What is the pattern of the string, and why without explode, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: where is the effort ? Do your home work urself, if problem raise, share here ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$j = mb_strlen($theString);
for ($k = 0; $k < $j; $k++) 
{
    $char = mb_substr($theString, $k, 1);
    $var_arr[$k] =  $char;
}
```

The above code don't use any pattern to split the string.

It ttakes one character at a time

```
EDIT suppose you have string

$s = 12.3.4.09.20

it will give the array as

array = ('1','2','.','3','.','4','.','0','9','.','2','0');
```

EDIT : COMPLETE CODE

```
<?php
$theString = "1.2.34.87";
$var_arr = array();
$j = mb_strlen($theString);
for ($k = 0; $k < $j; $k++) 
{
    $char = mb_substr($theString, $k, 1);
    $var_arr[$k] =  $char;
}
print_r($var_arr);
?>
```

go to http://phpfiddle.org/ and test over there

check the images as a proof
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell what will be its output? I am getting errors

Comment: i didnt get your code..so am asking to show me the complete program

Comment: its diff from what i want...my code:::$str = "1,2,3,4,5";        o/p should be this:  ([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 ) ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope your pattern is like below "this is string"
hence following code can be used for same:

```
<?php
// split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters,
// which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f
$keywords = preg_split("/ /", "this is string");
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Thanks
Bishop

Answer (score -1):

**My solution for this...**

```
$string = 'This-is-the-string';
$word = '';$warray = array();

for($i=0; $i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if($string[$i]=='-'){$warray[] = $word;$word = '';}
    else $word .= $string[$i];
}

if($word!='')$warray[] = $word;//Last word;

echo "<pre>";print_r($warray);die;
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This
    [1] => is
    [2] => the
    [3] => string
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $theString = "this is string";
    $var_arr = array();
    $j = mb_strlen($theString);
    $chars = "";
    for ($k = 0; $k < $j; $k++) 
    {

        $char = mb_substr($theString, $k, 1);
        if($char == " ")
        {
            $var_arr[] =  $chars;
            $chars = "";
        }
        else{
            $chars .= $char;
        }

        if( ($k + 1) == $j)
        {
            $var_arr[] =  $chars;
        }

    }
    print_r($var_arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = 'Rahul,Rohit,Sumeet,Abhi'; //your string 
$len = strlen($var);
$glue = ','; // place your glue here
$j=0;
for($i=0; $i<= $len;$i++){
    $arr[$j] .= trim($var[$i],$glue);   
    if($var[$i] == $glue){
        $j++;   
        continue;
    }
    else{

    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 $str  = "This is a string";
 $a =array();
 $word = "";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
      if($str[$i] == " "){
         $a[] = $word;
         $word = "";
      } else{
         $word .= $str[$i];
      }
    }

// for last word
if($word != ''){
    $a[] = $word;
}

print_r($a);
?>
```

Output:
    Array
    (
        [0] => This
        [1] => is
        [2] => a
        [3] => string
    )

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "imran,arsh,feroz,rushi";
$i = 0;
$word = '';
$temparray = [];

while(!empty($string[$i]))
{
    if($string[$i] == ','){
        $temparray[] = $word;
        $word = '';
    }else{
        $word .= $string[$i];
    }
    $i++;
}

if(!empty($word))
{
    $temparray[] = $word;
}
 
print_r($temparray);
output 
Array
(
    [0] => imran
    [1] => arsh
    [2] => feroz
    [3] => rushi
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).